# Garbage Collection Details: Is this object eligible for GC?

Tags: java, garbage-collection

I suppose that a program like this...

```
class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
        System.out.println("done");
    }

    protected void finalize() {
        System.out.println("this object is known to never be referenced.");
    }
}
```

...may possibly output `"this object is known to never be referenced."` before `"done"`. (Correct me if I'm wrong here!)

Furthermore, it is easy for a compiler/JVM to detect "unread locals". In the program below for instance, Eclipse notices that "*The local variable t is never read*".

However **would it be illegal for the JVM to output `"this object is known to never be referenced."` before `"done"` given the (.class version) of the program below?**

```
class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Test t = new Test();
        System.out.println("done");
    }

    protected void finalize() {
        System.out.println("this object is known to never be referenced.");
    }
}
```

Most documentation of garbage collection talk about reachability. Given the fact that `t` is never read, the object is obviously not "reachable", or?

References to the JLS are appreciated.

Comment: At least in C#/.net finalization of the object may occur before the "done" message even in the second program. That's because the jitter is free to optimize out the variable once it's clear that it won't be accessed anymore.

Comment: Aha, interesting. Perhaps it's the same for Java. I'm not sure by far though.

Comment: Well, it seems it was similar in Java.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In [12.6.1 of the Java Language Specification](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/execution.html#12.6.1) says:

> **12.6.1 Implementing Finalization**
>
> Every object can be characterized by two
>   attributes: it may be reachable,
>   finalizer- reachable, or unreachable,
>   and it may also be unfinalized,
>   finalizable, or finalized. A reachable
>   object is any object that can be
>   accessed in any potential continuing
>   computation from any live thread.
>   Optimizing transformations of a
>   program can be designed that reduce
>   the number of objects that are
>   reachable to be less than those which
>   would naively be considered reachable.
>
> For example, a compiler or code
>   generator may choose to set a variable
>   or parameter that will no longer be
>   used to null to cause the storage for
>   such an object to be potentially
>   reclaimable sooner.

The last phrase seems to me covering exactly the case you are asking about. The variable `t` can be set to `null` implicitly before the end of the scope, therefore making the object unreachable.

This in C++ would be a disaster because a lot of code depends on exact destruction timing at the end of scope (e.g. for locks).

Comment: Yep. Spot on! Good find. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

> ...may possibly output "this object is known to never be referenced." before "done".

There are three possible behaviors:

- the message is output before "done",
- the message is output after "done",
- the "this object is known to never be referenced" message is not output at all.

(In practice, the most likely behavior is that the last one.  In fact, it is a virtual certainty unless you generate lots of garbage between creating the `Test` instance and printing "done".)

> However would it be illegal for the JVM to output "this object is known to never be referenced." before "done" given the (.class version) of the program below?

No it would not be illegal.  The `Test` instance cannot *"be accessed in any potential continuing computation from any live thread"*, and is therefore unreachable.  Therefore it would be *legal* for the JVM to garbage collect it and finalize it immediately.

However, three events that must happen for the message to appear:

- the GC has to run,
- the GC has to detect the object as unreachable, and
- the GC has to finalize the object.

There is no guarantee that all of these events will happen before the application exits, yet alone in the window between creating the instance and printing "done".

---

The bottom line is that you should never depend on finalization occurring in a Java application.

Comment: Yes. Thanks. I know about the "no output at all". That's what happened when I tested it :-) That's why I formulated it as "would it be illegal for the JVM to..."

Comment: @aioobe - answered, I believe.

Comment: Ah, yep. With the quote from the JLS it's quite clear actually! Thanks again.

Comment: It's ages I'm not using Java ... but back then indeed the GC was apparently never finding objects given that all programs were just putting computers in trash mode :-D

Comment: @6502 - what version of Java was that?  If you are talking about Java 1.0, that was obsoleted in 1997.

Comment: @Stephen: close enough... I've been a certified Java 1.1 developer and since then my strategy about Java has been to stay a far as possible from it. So far I've been reasonably lucky with my avoidance strategy and I've no regrets about it. Every now and then I read articles about Java but I'm not really interested in it and its object obsessed approach. Honestly I really cannot think a field where Java is the best tool for the job (unless the job description is "do this with Java", of course).

Comment: @6502 - your opinion is noted.